# Adding requests to queue

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire

I have two requests. Each of them working different and returned different data. I need to create a queue where my first requests waiting while ending my second request after all indicator will stop. How i can do this?
This is my first requests:

```
func makeGetFav(userID:Int,completionHandler: (responseObject:JSON) -> ()) {
    alamoFireManager?.request(.GET, "url")
        .responseJSON {response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                if let httpError = response.result.error {
                    switch(httpError.code){
                    case -1009:
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Нету интернета!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        break
                    default:
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Повторите попытку!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        break
                    }
                } else { //no errors
                    let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                    print(statusCode)
                }
                return
            }
            completionHandler(responseObject: JSON(response.result.value!))
    }
}
```

And this is my second reuests:

```
func makeGetZakazDetail(orderID:Int,spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView,completionHandler: (responseObject:JSON) -> ()) {
    alamoFireManager?.request(.GET, "url")
        .responseJSON {response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                if let httpError = response.result.error {
                    switch(httpError.code){
                    case -1009:
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Нету интернета!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        break
                    default:
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Повторите попытку!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        break
                    }
                } else { //no errors
                    let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                    print(statusCode)
                }
                spinner.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                return
            }
            completionHandler(responseObject: JSON(response.result.value!))
    }
}
```